# Basic TPL - Application Hangs When running async code

Tags: async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm hoping this will be an easy question, as I'm still quite new to TPL, although very willing to learn.

I've built a basic WPF app that generates random numbers and hashes them, and it continues to do this until it matches a certain condition (the hash generated by the last numbers ends with the last characters specified by the user e.g. '37f' or '1f5e').

While I think I've managed to get the asynchronous behaviour right, the  application still noticeably hangs for a bit during the run, unless I introduce a Thread.Sleep for 10ms in the  method generating random numbers, as you will see below. I cannot figure out why this happens as the generator is outside the UI thread anyway...

```
private void ButtonBase2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (string.Equals(CommandButton2.Content.ToString(), "Start")) //we're checking the state in which the action button is: Start or Stop
  {
    _cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource(); // create a new cancellation token source
    var token = _cts2.Token; // assign it a new token
    CommandButton2.Content = "Stop"; // change the button state to stop
    var lastDigits = InputConstraint2.Text; // read constraint

    Task.Run(() => ContinuationMethod(lastDigits, false, token), token)
               .ContinueWith((t) => { CommandButton2.Content = "Start"; }, 
               TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
  } 
else
  {
    _cts2.Cancel();
    CommandButton2.Content = "Start"; // reset the button to start
  }
}


private void ContinuationMethod(string lastDigits, bool check, CancellationToken token)
{
  var random = new Random();
  while (!check)
    {
      try
      {
      if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();} 
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException e)
      {
      break;
      }

      var tuple = FindHashContinuation(lastDigits, random); 
      Dispatcher.Invoke(() => // call the dispatcher to switch the execution on the UI thread
            {
             Debug.WriteLine(tuple.Item1);
             TrialHash2.Text = tuple.Item1;
             TrialNumber2.Text = 
                tuple.Item2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            });
            check = tuple.Item3;
   }
```

Here it comes. Thread.Sleep below.

```
 private Tuple<string, double, bool> FindHashContinuation(string lastDigits, Random random)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10); //!!! This is what maintains the async behaviour in the app
        bool check = false;
        double newNo = random.Next();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newNo.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var hashstring = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        var hashString = hash.Aggregate("",
            (newstring, newbyte) => newstring + $"{newbyte:x2}");
        if (hashString.EndsWith(lastDigits))
        {
            check = true;
        }
        return new Tuple<string, double, bool>(hashString, newNo, check); // hash, actualNumber and check
    }
```

Any idea why that thread.sleep is needed?

Thanks for any replies.

Dragos

Comment: It's not needed. The code has too many issues. `Dispatcher.Invoke` tries to run *synchronously* on the UI thread. If you use `async/awai` properly you *don't* need it. After each `await` you'd be back on the UI thread. There are many more problems similar to this - `Task.Run` without awaiting, using `ContinueWith()` instead of `await`. *Thread.Sleep()* instead of `await Thread.Delay()`.

Comment: Why don't you use `async/await`? All supported .NET versions, ie 4.5.2 and later, provide it. The *only* scenario where you can't use it is if you target Windows XP which isn't supported anyway. Windows Vista and later support .NET 4.5+ and hence async/await

Comment: BTW the *only* thing that actually needs to run in the background is the call to `FindHashContinuation`. Everything else belongs to the UI thread. A call to `var response=await Task.Run(()=>FindHashContinuation(..));` would run it in the background without requiring calls to Dispatch.Invoker just to update the UI. The problem here is that *Random* isn't thread-safe. It's *not* used outside that method though, so it could be defined inside it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do have another version of the algorithm written using async/await (as you suggest) and it indeed doesn't hang as noticeably as the version using continuation (although I can still notice a slightly worse UI experience than when using thread.sleep to slow down the random number generator). However, I would still like to know why thread.sleep makes a difference, while I do acknowledge that async/await provides an easier syntax. I agree the Random class is not being accessed in thread-safe fashion -  but I don't think it should cause a slight hang in the application, should

Comment: You don't need Thread.Sleep. Without looking at the code it's not possible to know what's wrong. *This* code has too many problems and the *only* thing that actually needs to run in the background is `FindHashContinuation`. No `ContinueWith`, no `Thread.Sleep`, not `Dispatcher.Invoke` are needed